# Sum dataframe row values based on Shiny slider predicate

Tags: r, shiny

I'm building a Shiny app that reads in a csv and then displays three shiny `dataTables`, each displayed in its own `tabPanel`; i'm having trouble figuring out how to handle the third table.

The input csv contains values that look like

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
0.01, 0.02, 0.11, 0.00, 0.1
.
.
.
```

I'm trying to display a table that displays the values, and an additional column, that tally's row values that are smaller than a slider predicate. So if I set a slider value of `0.05` the desired output would be

```
tally, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
3, 0.01, 0.02, 0.11, 0.00, 0.1
```

In **UI.r** I've tried (excluding non-relevant code)

```
sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput("p-value", "P-Value Adjustment:",
                    min = 0.01, max = 0.1, value = 0.05, step = 0.01),
        ),

mainPanel(
        #excluding two other panels that work correctly 
        tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel("Interactive-Data",
                     dataTableOutput("interactive.table"))
          )
     )
```

and then in **Server.r**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
   value.frame <- read.csv("path/to/file")

   sliderValues <- reactive({

    input.frame <- data.frame(
        Name = c("p-value"),
        Value = c(input$p-value))

    data.frame(cbind(input.frame, value.frame, stringsAsFactor=FALSE))

    })

#I'm lost here
output$interactive.table = renderDataTable({
    data.frame$tally <- rowSums(data.frame < p-value)
    data.frame

    })
```

I'm getting lost with how to use the input from the `sliderInput` to dynamically recalculate the value of the `interactive.table$tally` column. Is `renderDataTable` appropriate or is there another way to go about this?

Comment: In the `output$interactive.table` I would think that just having `value.frame$tally <- rowSums(value.frame < input$p-value` would be sufficient. Why the extra `reactive` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to do what you are asking:

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI = pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Title"),
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("p.value", "P-Value Adjustment:",
                min = 0.01, max = 0.1, value = 0.05, step = 0.01)),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Interactive-Data",
               dataTableOutput("interactive.table"))))
)
shinyServer = function(input,output){
  value.frame <- data.frame(matrix(round(runif(60,0,0.2),2),ncol=6))
  output$interactive.table <- renderDataTable({
    tally <- sapply(1:nrow(value.frame), function(i)
             rowSums(value.frame[i,2:ncol(value.frame)] < input$p.value,na.rm=T))
    df <- data.frame("p-value"=input$p.value,tally,value.frame)
    colnames(df)[3:8] <- c(as.character(0:5))
    df
  })}
runApp(list(
  ui = shinyUI,
  server = shinyServer
))
```

There are several problematic aspects of your code. Here are a few:

1. Referencing `p-value` rather than `input$p-value`
2. Using `p-value` as a variable name. R thinks `input$p-value` is `input$p` minus `value`. You can get around this by using `input$"p-value"` but this makes the code almost unintelligible, so I changd `p-value` to `p.value`.
3. You reference `data.frame` in the call to `renderDataTable(...)` as if it was a variable.
4. Most of the functions that create or return data frames prepend `X` to any column names that start with a number, so if you insist on numbers for column names you have to get rid of those `X's`.
5. `rowSums(...)` doesn't work that way.